# MQTT Android Mosquitto client

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto

Just a quick question: I just got working MQTT Mosquitto broker on RPi, same RPi have a client that makes ESP module send temperature from DS sensors(also Mosquitto client), but it isn't really important. I want to subscribe on the data topic with Android phone and display the temperature, but I can't really find any Mosquitto library for Android, the closest thing I found was 'Eclipse Paho', but I don't know if these are compatibile, may I count on your help? And to be sure: I never programmed any Android stuff, so I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mosquitto broker is an implementation of the MQTT standard (and also part of the Eclipse Paho project).

The Eclipse Paho Android Service is a client implementation of the MQTT standard.

Both will interact with each other according to the standard.

Comment: I tried Paho's example, but it seems been not working with Mosquitto broker. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Not with "seams been not working" as a description. Ask a new question and include a LOT MORE detail